# Add Reference to Assembly but Not in Reference Manager

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, reference

I'm using .NET 4.5. I want to use this library http://gendictedit.codeplex.com/.

It says there's an error:

> Error  1   The type 'System.ComponentModel.Design.CollectionEditor' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. C:\Users\Sam\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\RainingChainQuestApplication\RainingChainQuestApplication\Form_Npc.cs    41  37  RainingChainQuestApplication`

When I look in the Reference Manager, there is only `System.Design v4.0.0.0`.

Is there a way to still use that library while using .NET 4.5? From what I understand, the library relies on .NET 2.x? Is that true?

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Does adding a reference to the `4.0` version work?

Comment: You could try a redirect policy on that library from v2 to v4 (don't know if it had breaking changes)

Comment: @Cameron, Okay, I'm dumb. Using v4.0.0.0 removes the error. Thanks.